# Cordova Purchase Plugin validate subscription offline

Tags: ios, validation, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova app utilizing the Purchase plugin for a subscription.  On both Android and iOS if the app launches offline the store will throw an error that it can't connect to the store.  This by itself is fine.  I can check if they are still in a trial and if so grant access to the rest of the app.

The issue is if they are either not in a trial or have previously purchased a subscription.

If they are not in a trial I think they're basically SOL but I'm open to creative suggestions.

But more importantly is that on iOS if they have an active subscription the plugin will not validate that subscription because it can't contact the store to do the validation.  It will throw an error.  On Android it will validate the subscription whether the phone is offline or not.

So... my primary question is... how can I validate an iOS subscription offline with the cordova purchase plugin?  Is this supposed to work offline out of the box for iOS or did I mess up the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions are supposed to be validated with a server, which isn't possible offline. You can implement your own strategy (allowing or denying access by default) when the subscription status can't be validated. You can remember the last subscription status in localStorage.

The right answer all depend on what your subscription gives access to.

Downloadable content? Allow to download things while subscribed (and online, of course), give access to the downloaded content while offline.

Comment: New development: we now provide a hosted backend service for receipts validations at https://billing.fovea.cc -- it aims to make things simpler for people who like to add subscriptions to their cordova apps without headaches.